# DigitalOcean - OpenLiteSpeed WordPress Domain Name Issues

Tags: wordpress, dns

I'm pointing my domain name www.patrickwall.com at ns1.digitalocean.com, ns2.digitalocean.com and ns3.digitalocean.com, and it's propagated correctly, but I'm unable to get my website to appear in a browser. When I enter my domain name in WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) in my WordPress settings and restart the server, the domain cannot be found. And the wp-admin although accessible is now unstyled. When I change the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to myIP address the site is still not working although the wp-admin is now styled. I've tried adding my domain in wp-config.php define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.patrickwall.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.patrickwall.com' ); which is picked up by the WordPress admin settings, but still doesn't resolve the issue. I've set up wordpress previously on DigitalOcean without these issues. The only difference is that this time I 1-click installed the OpenLiteSpeed version of WordPress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the OpenLiteSpeed + WordPress 1-click image on Digital Ocean, after the machine has been installed, you have to also add your domain to the virtual host for it to go into effect.

In the quickstart guide, you'll find how to access the Web Server Control Panel: https://docs.litespeedtech.com/Cloud/wordpress/#web-server-control-panel-access

When you've logged into the console, you have to go to "Virtual Hosts", then click on the small "Search" icon (View), go to "General", and in the "General" section you'd click the Edit button in the upper right corner, enter your domain `patrickwall.com` and in Domain Aliases, you'd enter `www.patrickwall.com`.

After this, go to "Listeners", and under "Default" and "Defaultssl", you have to modify the Virtual Host mapping to contain your domain as well: `patrickwall.com,www.patrickwall.com`

and then restart OpenLiteSpeed by clicking the green button in the upper right corner next to "LSWS PID".

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, the OpenLiteSpeed + WordPress 1-click image on Digital Ocean has a new **auto setup script** for Domain and SSL supported.

SSH into the console, an interactive script that runs will first prompt you for your domain or subdomain.

You can press CTRL+C and continue to SSH. The prompt will open again the next time you log in, and will continue to do so until you finish the whole setup.

```
Please input a valid domain:
Please verify it is correct. [y/N]
```

You can also automatically apply Let's Encrypt SSL if your domain is pointed to this server already. Enter y and your email address to finish the process.

```
Do you wish to issue a Let's encrypt certificate for this domain? [y/N]
Please enter your E-mail:
Please verify it is correct: [y/N]
```

Once finished, you should see Certificate has been successfully installed...

```
Do you wish to force HTTPS rewrite rule for this domain? [y/N]
```

Once finished, force HTTPS rules will be applied

```
Do you wish to update the system which include the web server? [Y/n]
```

This script will automatically go away after your domain has been added.

More details please check [here](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/wordpress/#step-3)